# is the common practice in python to put __init__ in the beginning of class definition?

Tags: python

I wonder whether the recommended practice is to put **init** in the beginning of class definition or to put interface functions first:

```
class examp1:
    def ifmethod1(self):
         pass
    def ifmethod2(self):
         pass
    def __init__(self):
         pass
```

VS.

```
class examp1:
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    def ifmethod1(self):
         pass
    def ifmethod2(self):
         pass
```

Comment: Put it in the middle so it looks like a sandwich, people seem to like sandwiches.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people put it first, but every one can have their own opinion and you'll find arguments for both.

To me, being first is simply useful because it's helpful to know `__init__` quickly.

In an effort to help coders of other languages grasp Python quickly, [ibiblio.org](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-init.html) says "`__init__` is analogous to a constructor". In that spirit, it would often be put first — constructors in other languages are almost always listed first.

In one example, the [Google style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) for Python, it is always listed first.

Comment: for the google style guide though the guide doesn't explicitly say so all of its examples put __init__ in the beginning

Comment: the google style guide is just a company's opinion as to where to put it -- it's not objectively important.  it's 'common' to put `__init__.py` first, and [pep-0008 examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) do so, but ultimately, it's a stylistic decision

Comment: I feel like it's clear that "In one example" means "just a company's opinion". I also feel that it is clear that "it is always listed first" doesn't necessarily mean that the style guide says to do it explicitly. And I feel that it is clear that "A lot of people ... can have their own opinion ..." means "ultimately, it's a stylistic decision".